# Can I run a middleware function at "expires" in mongoose.js?

Tags: mongoose

I am using expires on documents of a schema, like so:
expire: {type: Date, default: Date.now(), expires: 9000 }

But what I wish to achieve is to redirect the document to another mongo database using another mongoose connection before the document is deleted, that is to make an archive for all expired documents from that schema. Is that even possible in mongoose? if so how?

PS: I know i can make an offline process by myself to run over all docs in that schema and check that field manually and do the whole thing by myself, but if mongoose has a way, it must be more efficient than "do-it-yourself".

Thank you.

Comment: Nope.  Similar question was asked a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808931/ttl-expiration-of-mongoose-referenced-document/22814693#22814693

Comment: Thanks, maybe because it's new i didnt see it in the results.